# Mysql - Calculate rank grouped by two columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a mysql table like so:

```
          Tbl
[Username   Number  Type]
  manos       5       A
  manos       6       B
  maria       2       A
  maria       3       B
  maria       1       C
  nick        7       A
  nick        4       C
  aaron       8       A
```

I want to create a view where I will have the ranks of each user (by larger Number), grouped by `Type`, in comparison to the other users in each Type. More specifically, I would like the output to be:

```
[Username     Rank   Type]
   manos       3       A
   manos       1       B
   maria       4       A
   maria       2       B
   maria       2       C
   nick        2       A
   nick        1       C
   aaron       1       A
```

I have tried the following:

```
 select Username, count(*) as Rank, Type
 from Tbl as aw
 where
    Number <= (
       select Number
       from Tbl
       where Type = aw.Type
    )
 group by Username, Type
```

The result is that I get the `Subquery returns more than 1 row` error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: changed the names of columns as suggested. Also a fiddle to help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55ec3f

Edit 2: Some clarification and corrections to the "all combinations rank". 
Lets say we have another table called `Teams`:

```
          Teams
[Username   Team]
  manos       T1 
  manos       T2
  maria       T1
  maria       T2
  nick        T1
  nick        T2
  aaron       T3
```

In this case I want to extract ranks on each combination of group(s) and Types, i.e. for Manos I would like:

- Rank against people in T1 with type A
- Rank against people in T2 with type A
- Rank against people in T1 with type B
- Rank against people in T2 with type B
- Rank against people in T1 AND T2 with type A
- Rank against people in T1 AND T2 with type B

Comment: Ok, After re-reading twice, I still don't understand what you are expecting here. :(

Comment: You have the first table in mysql, you must produce the second. For example of all people in group A, manos is ranked 3rd out of 4.

Comment: I understand the ranks, but I don't understand why manos comes first in the result.

Comment: The order is meaningless, pay no attention to it! Only ranks are useful :) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: True, fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of sanity, I renamed your `group` column...

```
   SELECT username
     , user_group
     , number
     , CASE WHEN @prev=user_group THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
     , @prev:=user_group 
  FROM my_table x
     , (SELECT @prev:=null, @i:=0) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY user_group
     , number DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe any ideas for the group's combinations? :)

Comment: @ManosTsardoulias I'm afraid I don't understand that aspect of the problem.

Comment: I corrected the initial description. Another table is introduced which holds the teams every person is in!

Answer (score -1):

Correct code:

```
select Username, (select Number
   from Tbl as t
   where t.Type = aw.Type and t.Username = aw.Username) as Rank, Type from Tbl as aw where
Number <= (
   select Number
   from Tbl as t
   where t.Type = aw.Type and t.Username = aw.Username
) group by Username, Type
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns 1 for everyone since you equal with the same username in the inner query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55ec3f/1

Comment: This effectively substitutes 'rank' for 'number' which again, is not what's wanted.

Comment: And, yes `group` is reserved. Thank you, [Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry)